# Xcode version on Mac OSx Lion 10.7.2

Tags: xcode, macos

I installed mac osx lion using vmware on my windows 7 machine. When I'm trying to install xcode 4.3 or 4.3.1 it is asking me upgrade os to 10.7.3 . Is there no xcode version for 10.7.2?

Answer (score 1):

As far I remember, XCode 4.2 does run on 10.7.2.